# GitHub Gist API limitations

Tags: android, database, api, github, gist

coders.

Imagine that I have android app that users are using for getting fresh information about PC components.
Very specific information that I cant pull elsewhere. This information is generated as 10 excel tables with few hundreds rows each and updated each month.
I am looking for a way to push this updates to end user.

My question is:
Is it legal to use gist as data provider for my app ? Is there any better service to pull small data base for free? I know about gist 1mb size truncated , 10 mb raw and hidden limit on ip api requests, is there are more limitations I need  to consider?

My idea was to hardcode in app a link to "main" gist that will be filled with links to gists with monthly data updates.

Ty in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do not ask for legal opinions on Stack Overflow. We are not lawyers. Try https://law.stackexchange.com/ Your best bet is to read the GitHub licensing documentation and determine the correct answer for yourself. I would not use GithHub/Gist as a free database service. There are many very low-cost/free solutions that are better suited. Google search.